# Ajax request on JS doesn't pass some number of %

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-post

I have a simple Ajax post request on JavaScript like:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://example.com/phphandler.php", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send("mykey="+myString);
```

I need to pass a dozens of the % symbols in the `myString` text and in such case it's not being passed to the phphandler. When I remove all the percents from the string or leave just a few ones, the request works fine. Is there some limitation(s) for the % symbol and how to eliminate it?

**UPDATED:** I've figured out that the problem was caused by the following part of my string: `%5c`

Is there something else similar to it that also may cause the problem?

Comment: I think you should try to escape the "%" character.
Maybe with %25

Comment: I've updated the question